# Regular measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-measures

I need to prove that if $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then:
$$
\mu: \mathcal{L}_n \to \mathbb{\bar{R}}
$$
$$ 
E \mapsto \int_{E} f(x) dx
$$
 is a regular sign measure. However, I can't verify that $\mu$ is regular. Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: Observe that $\int_E f(x)dx=\int f(x)\chi_E(x)dx$, where $\chi_E$ is the indicator function of $E$, and use the dominated convergence theorem, since $|f(x)\chi_E(x)|\leq|f(x)|$ and $f\in L^1$.

Comment: But I would not have to verify that $\mu(E)=\inf\{\mu(\Omega):\Omega \ \mbox{is a open and} \ E \subset \Omega \}$ or else that $\mu(E)=\sup\{\mu(K):K \ \mbox{is a compact and} \ K \subset E \}$? How can I conclude this from the dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: Thanks! I did it.